# Access FieldItem object from Widget

Tags: entities, database

I have a custom FieldItem with a method doing a calculation on the field's values:

```
class MyFieldItem extends FieldItemBase {
  ...
  public function getAmountInEuros() {
    $amount = $this->get('amount')->getValue();
    $currency = $this->get('currency')->getValue();
    $exchange_rate = $this->getExchangeRate($currency);
    return $exchange_rate * $amount;
  }
  ...
```

I have a custom widget for that FieldItem where I need to do exactly the same calculation.

```
class MyWidget extends WidgetBase {
  ...
  public function getAmountInEuros() {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Of course, I would prefer to write down this logic only in one place, preferably in the FieldItem definition.

**How can I access the corresponding FieldItem from within the widget?**

(The code is just a minimal example that should show the principal problem with a complex field and widget that work otherwise.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are building a single form element you have $delta to get the field item.

```
public function formElement(FieldItemListInterface $items, $delta, array $element, array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  $euros = $items[$delta]->getAmountInEuros();
```

In other widget methods you can loop over $items.